# Android Facebook Login using new Firebase : App gets redirected to the login screen even after allowing permission

Tags: android, firebase, facebook-login, firebase-authentication, facebook-authentication

I am trying to implement facebook login using firebase. I created a new Facebook app and got the app id and app secret , entered the app id and app secret in the firebase console and enabled facebook login.

In android studio saved the app id in the strings.xml. After that added the facebook sdk dependency. Then i wrote the required code in the AndroidManifest file and the LoginActivity.java. I added a button in the activity_login.xml.

**When i run the app and click on the Login with Facebook button ,it opens the Facebook view which asks me to allow permission for accessing email ,profile etc.After i click on accept the app redirects to the login screen and nothing happens.
I am really frustrated please help. Thanks in advance.**

Here is the code

AndroidManifest.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.androidmate.anuj.trynew">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId" android:value="@string/fb_app_id"/>

        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".HomeActivity"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
            />
        <activity android:name=".login.LoginActivity"></activity>
        <activity android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity"
            android:configChanges=
                "keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar"
            android:label="@string/app_name" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

LoginActivity.java

```
public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {

SignInButton btLoginWhithGoogle;
Button btLoginWithFacebook;
FirebaseAuth mAuth;
FirebaseUser mUser;
CallbackManager callbackManager;

private static final int RC_SIGN_IN = 9000;
private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
private static final String TAG = "LoginActivity";
private FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener mAuthListener;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

    mAuth= FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    //Facebook Login
    mAuthListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
            FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
            if (user != null) {
                // User is signed in
                Log.d(TAG, "onAuthStateChanged:signed_in:" + user.getUid());
                startActivity(new Intent(LoginActivity.this,HomeActivity.class));
                finish();
            } else {
                // User is signed out
                Log.d(TAG, "onAuthStateChanged:signed_out");
            }
        }
    };

    mAuth.addAuthStateListener(mAuthListener);

    FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
    callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
    LoginManager.getInstance().registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
            saveFacebookLoginData("facebook", loginResult.getAccessToken());
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancel() {

        }

        @Override
        public void onError(FacebookException error) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "" + error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });

    btLoginWithFacebook = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btLoginWithFacebook);
    btLoginWhithGoogle = (SignInButton) findViewById(R.id.btLoginWithGoogle);
    btLoginWhithGoogle.setOnClickListener(this);
    btLoginWithFacebook.setOnClickListener(this);

    GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
                                .requestIdToken(getString(R.string.default_web_client_id))
                                .requestEmail()
                                .build();
    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                        .enableAutoManage(this /* FragmentActivity */, this /* OnConnectionFailedListener */)
                        .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, gso)
                        .build();
}

private void saveFacebookLoginData(String facebook, AccessToken accessToken) {
        String token = accessToken.getToken();
    AuthCredential credential = FacebookAuthProvider.getCredential(token);
    mAuth.signInWithCredential(credential)
            .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "signInWithCredential:onComplete:" + task.isSuccessful());

                    // If sign in fails, display a message to the user. If sign in succeeds
                    // the auth state listener will be notified and logic to handle the
                    // signed in user can be handled in the listener.
                    if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                        Log.w(TAG, "signInWithCredential", task.getException());
                        Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Authentication failed.",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }else{
                        startActivity(new Intent(LoginActivity.this, HomeActivity.class));
                    }

                    // ...
                }
            });
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()){
        case R.id.btLoginWithGoogle:

            Intent sighniIntent = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(mGoogleApiClient);
            startActivityForResult(sighniIntent,RC_SIGN_IN);
            break;
        case R.id.btLoginWithFacebook:
            LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithReadPermissions(this, Arrays.asList("public_profile", "user_friends", "email"));

            break;

    }
}


@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if(requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN){
        GoogleSignInResult result = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInResultFromIntent(data);
        if(result.isSuccess()){
            GoogleSignInAccount account = result.getSignInAccount();
            firebaseAuthWithGoogle(account);
        }else{

        }
    }

}

private void firebaseAuthWithGoogle(GoogleSignInAccount account) {

    AuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(account.getIdToken(),null);

    mAuth.signInWithCredential(credential).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
            if(!task.isSuccessful()){
                String error = String.valueOf(task.getException());
                Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this,"Login Failed :"+ error,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }else {

                startActivity(new Intent(LoginActivity.this, HomeActivity.class));
                finish();

            }
        }
    });

}

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
    Log.d(TAG, "onConnectionFailed:" + connectionResult);
    Toast.makeText(this, "Google Play Services error.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}


}
```

activity_login.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@mipmap/login_back"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.androidmate.anuj.trynew.login.LoginActivity">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:src="@mipmap/img_toolbar_logo"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        />


    <com.google.android.gms.common.SignInButton
        android:id="@+id/btLoginWithGoogle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/btLogin"
        android:layout_marginTop="280dp"
        android:padding="20dp"

        />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btLoginWithFacebook"
        style="?android:textAppearanceSmall"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="@color/com_facebook_button_background_color"

        android:padding="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:text="Login with Facebook"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="#fff"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this code.

```
LoginManager mLoginManager;

//Firebase Variables
private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
private FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener mAuthStateListener;

private CallbackManager mCallbackManager;

//Inside onCreate()
FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());

mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

    mAuthStateListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
            FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
            updateUI(user);
        }
    };

    mCallbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
     btnFacebookSignIn = (LoginButton) findViewById(R.id.button_facebook_signin);
    btnFacebookSignIn.setReadPermissions("email","public_profile");
    btnFacebookSignIn.registerCallback(mCallbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
            Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, Constants.LOGINSUCCESSFUL, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            SharedPreferences sharedPref = getSharedPreferences(Constants.SHAREDPREFERENCE_USER_PROFILE,MODE_PRIVATE);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
            editor.putString(Constants.USERLOGINTYPE,"facebook");
            editor.apply();
            handleFacebookAccessToken(loginResult.getAccessToken());
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancel() {
            Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, Constants.LOGINFAILED, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(FacebookException error) {
            Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, error.getMessage().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

       @Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    mAuth.addAuthStateListener(mAuthStateListener);
}


@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    if(mAuthStateListener != null) {
        mAuth.removeAuthStateListener(mAuthStateListener);
    }
}


// [START onactivityresult]
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    mCallbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
// [END onactivityresult]

private void handleFacebookAccessToken(AccessToken token) {
    // ...
    AuthCredential credential = FacebookAuthProvider.getCredential(token.getToken());
    mAuth.signInWithCredential(credential)
            .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {

                    // If sign in fails, display a message to the user. If sign in succeeds
                    // the auth state listener will be notified and logic to handle the
                    // signed in user can be handled in the listener.
                    if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                        Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Authentication failed.",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }

                    // ...
                }
            });
}
// [END auth_with_facebook]

              private void updateUI(FirebaseUser user) {
    if (user != null) {
    //Code here for what you want to do after login
       }
      }


   private void FacebookSignOut() {
    if (AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken() == null) {
        return; // already logged out
    }else {
        new GraphRequest(AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(), "/me/permissions/", null, HttpMethod.DELETE, new GraphRequest
                .Callback() {
            @Override
            public void onCompleted(GraphResponse graphResponse) {

                LoginManager.getInstance().logOut();

            }
        }).executeAsync();
    }
}
```